# Error while installing Sprangular. undefined method `sprockets_v2?' for Ngannotate:Module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spree, sprockets

Thanks in advance

I am following this to install sprangular locally.

https://github.com/sprangular/sprangular/wiki/setup-guide

I tried manual method also its giving same error.

getting this error while `bundle install`

```
/home/spider/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@rails-4.1.8/gems/bundler-1.12.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:89:in `rescue in block (2 levels) in require': There was an error while trying to load the gem 'sprangular'. (Bundler::GemRequireError)
Gem Load Error is: undefined method `sprockets_v2?' for Ngannotate:Module
Backtrace for gem load error is:
/home/spider/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@rails-4.1.8/gems/ngannotate-rails-1.2.2/lib/ngannotate/rails/railtie.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
/home/spider/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@rails-4.1.8/gems/polyglot-0.3.5/lib/polyglot.rb:65:in `require'
/home/spider/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@rails-4.1.8/gems/polyglot-0.3.5/lib/polyglot.rb:65:in `require'
/home/spider/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@rails-4.1.8/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
/home/spider/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@rails-4.1.8/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
/home/spider/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@rails-4.1.8/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
/home/spider/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@rails-4.1.8/gems/ngannotate-rails-1.2.2/lib/ngannotate/rails.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
/home/spider/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@rails-4.1.8/gems/polyglot-0.3.5/lib/polyglot.rb:65:in `require'
/home/spider/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@rails-4.1.8/gems/polyglot-0.3.5/lib/polyglot.rb:65:in `require'
/home/spider/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@rails-4.1.8/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
/home/spider/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@rails-4.1.8/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
/home/spider/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@rails-4.1.8/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
/home/spider/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@rails-4.1.8/gems/sprangular-0.1.0/lib/sprangular.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
/home/spider/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@rails-4.1.8/gems/bundler-1.12.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86:in `require'
/home/spider/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@rails-4.1.8/gems/bundler-1.12.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86:in `block (2 levels) in require'
/home/spider/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@rails-4.1.8/gems/bundler-1.12.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `each'
/home/spider/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@rails-4.1.8/gems/bundler-1.12.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `block in require'
/home/spider/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@rails-4.1.8/gems/bundler-1.12.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `each'
/home/spider/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@rails-4.1.8/gems/bundler-1.12.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `require'
/home/spider/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@rails-4.1.8/gems/bundler-1.12.1/lib/bundler.rb:102:in `require'
/home/spider/Dropbox/Round360/myapp/config/application.rb:14:in `<top (required)>'
/home/spider/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@rails-4.1.8/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:146:in `require'
/home/spider/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@rails-4.1.8/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:146:in `require_application_and_environment!'
/home/spider/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@rails-4.1.8/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:133:in `generate_or_destroy'
/home/spider/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@rails-4.1.8/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:51:in `generate'
/home/spider/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@rails-4.1.8/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
/home/spider/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@rails-4.1.8/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
bin/rails:4:in `require'
bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
Bundler Error Backtrace:
    from /home/spider/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@rails-4.1.8/gems/bundler-1.12.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:85:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /home/spider/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@rails-4.1.8/gems/bundler-1.12.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `each'
    from /home/spider/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@rails-4.1.8/gems/bundler-1.12.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `block in require'
    from /home/spider/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@rails-4.1.8/gems/bundler-1.12.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `each'
    from /home/spider/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@rails-4.1.8/gems/bundler-1.12.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `require'
    from /home/spider/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@rails-4.1.8/gems/bundler-1.12.1/lib/bundler.rb:102:in `require'
    from /home/spider/Dropbox/Round360/myapp/config/application.rb:14:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/spider/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@rails-4.1.8/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:146:in `require'
    from /home/spider/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@rails-4.1.8/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:146:in `require_application_and_environment!'
    from /home/spider/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@rails-4.1.8/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:133:in `generate_or_destroy'
    from /home/spider/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@rails-4.1.8/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:51:in `generate'
    from /home/spider/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@rails-4.1.8/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
    from /home/spider/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@rails-4.1.8/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Did you install js runtime or install gem `ruby racer`. Try `sudo apt-get install nodejs` in linux machine or `brew install nodejs` in osx.

Answer (score 0):

Try `bundle update` instead of `bundle install` . and also do you have node.js installed?

Comment: this problem is not because of node.js

Comment: I tried to duplicate on my machine but it worked perfectly fine for me.